# How to get required data from this kind of wrong JSON format?

Tags: objective-c, json, string, format, nsdictionary

There is syntax error in this response(google api response),I want to get Points' data from this response. how can i get it.

```
{
    tooltipHtml:" (9.6 km / 18 mins)",
    polylines:[
    {
    id:"route0",
    points:"_y}oBwxiaM{CdCaAh@}IvAgAB_BOqLgBgCXqFhB_GdCoAnAcGlHuAjA_Bb@oBAy@MsVqI{DgBgC{AmE{EqA{Be@oCLcDvDaRPeDGiBY_Bi@mAyAiB{@g@aC_AyT{FyCcBqMoIqQ{I??URSCIMJ]UuASuGN}THiCd@_GWyGiB}GmCyPwAwLqCqq@}CqMsBkMGiFMOWwDIwDg@mC]}@??k@s@oBD??yDvAqPpKeEfBcJdGoD~@sBAqAYcBm@mBY??`@g@l@[??RyAQoA",
    levels:"B??@???@?@??@??A?@??@???@???@??@??BB?????????@???????????BB?BB???@????BB?BB?B",
    numLevels:4,
    zoomFactor:16
    }
    ]
    }
```

http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=18.507853,73.783338&daddr=18.545277,73.803988 is api what i am using.

Comment: So, how about telling us which error you get?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815586/convert-invalid-json-into-valid-json

Answer (score 0):

Use this `NSJSONSerialization` if you want the json data

```
+ (NSData *)dataWithJSONObject:(id)obj options:(NSJSONWritingOptions)opt 
error:(NSError **)error
```

Comment: problem is, i am not getting valid json format in response. is there general way to make invalid json (like this) make valid json ?