# How do i add these JSONS

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to merge some jsons. I tried [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286208/merging-two-json-in-php) but I think they don't fit my needs.

I got 2(or more) of these jsons

```
{
    item: {
        icon: "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4922_obj_sprite.gif?id=2",
        icon_large: "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4922_obj_big.gif?id=2",
        id: 2,
        type: "Default",
        typeIcon: "http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Default",
        name: "Cannonball",
        description: "Ammo for the Dwarf Cannon.",
        current: {
            trend: "neutral",
            price: 208
        },
        today: {
            trend: "positive",
            price: "+8"
        },
        members: "true",
        day30: {
            trend: "positive",
            change: "+8.0%"
        },
        day90: {
            trend: "negative",
            change: "-4.0%"
        },
        day180: {
            trend: "positive",
            change: "+9.0%"
        }
    }
}
```

How do I add them to something like this?

```
{
    items: [
        {
            icon: "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4922_obj_sprite.gif?id=2",
            icon_large: "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4922_obj_big.gif?id=2",
            id: 2,
            type: "Default",
            typeIcon: "http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Default",
            name: "Cannonball",
            description: "Ammo for the Dwarf Cannon.",
            //Same other stuff here
        },
        {
            icon: "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4922_obj_sprite.gif?id=2",
            icon_large: "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4922_obj_big.gif?id=2",
            id: 2,
            type: "Default",
            typeIcon: "http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Default",
            name: "Cannonball",
            description: "Ammo for the Dwarf Cannon.",
            //Same other stuff here     
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @AlexAndrei I tried the answers in the link and some close to them. The first gave me NULL and the second gave me the lasted json i tried to merge.

Comment: somehow missed your first sentence, apologies. Can you please post all json strings, or can i just duplicate the first?

Comment: What should the resulting json look like

Comment: @dlporter98 like the bottom json

Comment: where does the json come from; are they each stored a file?

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. Choose the answer that helped you and mark it as accepted, or post your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the initial `JSON` string is not valid, the keys are not enclosed in double quotes, so we need to fix this.

Sample code using the initial string repeated 10 times

```
<?php

$string = file_get_contents('sample.json');

//var_dump($string);

$data = jsonDecode($string);

for ($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
    $list['items'][] = $data['item'];

print json_encode($list);

function jsonDecode($string, $assoc=true, $fixNames=true){
  if(strpos($string, '(') === 0){
    $string = substr($string, 1, strlen($string) - 2); // remove outer ( and )
  }
  if($fixNames){
    $string = preg_replace("/(?<!\"|'|\w)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+?)(?!\"|'|\w)\s?:/", "\"$1\":", $string);
  }
  return json_decode($string, $assoc);
}
```

the json fixing function was take from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17748840/5043552
the output is as requested

Comment: I believe the keys are encoded when I decode them. So can I skip your decoding part?

Comment: of course, if the fix is not necessary remove it and just construct the list. You can easily inspect the JSON response and decide this

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where each of the json structures are coming from but I assume it will be something that can be iterated through:

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach ($jsonStructs as $json)
{
    $j = json_decode($json, true);
    $finalArray['items'][] = $j['item'];
}

$finalJson = json_encode( $finalArray);
```

I take each of the json structures and decode it to a php array. I then take the item value from it and place it into another array that will hold each one.

Finally, I encode the finally array to json which will give you what you asked for.