# Convert invalid json into valid one in bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I get invalid JSON from a script, e.g.

```
{
  name: "Leo",
  active: true
}
```

Is there a bash install-able tool I can use to pipe that output and turn it into valid JSON so can be processed by jq given jq doesn't support it ?

This question is similar to [Convert invalid json into valid json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815586/convert-invalid-json-into-valid-json) except I need a command line utility and not some replace based php code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Hjson](http://hjson.org/) does this kind of thing really well.

```
$ hjson -j <<EOF
> {
>   name: "Leo",
>   active: true
> }
> EOF
{
  "name": "Leo",
  "active": true
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I'll use the python version `pip3 install hjson && cli53 list | python -m hjson.tool -j` Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

The jq FAQ at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#processing-not-quite-valid-json lists several tools (including hjson) for converting near-JSON to JSON.  Some of them can be used as bash commands, e.g.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/any-json, which is particularly versatile.

Incidentally, since jq allows JSON to be specified in a jq program in a flexible way (e.g. quotation marks around key names can be omitted and "#" comments can be added), you can use jq itself to convert many instances of not-quite JSON to JSON.  Using your example, if the not-quite JSON text is in a file named input.nqj, then the invocation:

```
$ jq -n -f input.nqj
```

would produce:

```
{
  "name": "Leo",
  "active": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I don't know how easy it is to deploy Hjson (from Steve Bennett's answer), here's a more lightweight alternative, using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/\b\([^:"]*\)\b\s*:/"\1":/g' <<EOF
> {
>   name: "Leo",
>   active: true
> }
> EOF
{
  "name": "Leo",
  "active": true
}
```

Note that this is more specific to the example you've provided in the question: it will only fix missing quotation around keys. Also, it might be too aggressive about that, as, for example, integer keys would be quoted as well.

Comment: You were faster :) I had 
sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]*\):/"\1":/'