# Parse error while decoding json to array

Tags: php, json

Below  is my JSON string

```
{"ticket_action":"Updated","id":"4214","title":"test_123456","description" :"This request was closed and merged into request #4192 "test_2".","tags": "closed_by_merge","status": "Closed","update_time":"2016-02-26T00:56:07-08:00","phone":"+919898989898"}
```

When I am trying to decode it using `json_decode($json_string,true)`;
it is not decoding.

I think issue is because of "test_2"."  in json string (nested double quotes).
I have tried with escape function but did't get any success.
Is their any way to decode this string?

Comment: your json is not valid . Please check on `JSONLINT`:-  http://jsonlint.com/  .that's why you are getting error. so first correct your json format

Comment: how have you created your JSON String ?

Comment: I have got this json string in Zendesk API response.

Comment: show the full code how's you created your json string.  and you problem is occur here:- `"description" :"This request was closed and merged into request #4192 "test_2".",`. it should be something like:- `"description" :"This request was closed and merged into request #4192 \"test_2\".",`

Comment: I have not created this JSON, I got json in 3re party API response.

Comment: @Shirish can you give us url that you've used to get this JSON?

Comment: @Halayem actually it is webhook response from zendesk.

Comment: just have a try at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815586/convert-invalid-json-into-valid-json

Comment: @justin I have followed the link but didnt get success. I have issue with only "description" key and its value. still didn't got any solution.