# php code to convert invalid json string to valid json string

Tags: php, json

how can I convert following invalid json string to valid in php
I need solution in php.
Please give me a way to convert this input json to output json

input:

```
{
            account : 'rogersrmisports',
            brand : 'Sportsnet',
            tags : '',
            cmsid : '2912963',
            wordCount : '3197',
            publishDate : 'July 11, 2016',
            products : '',
            pages : 'sportsnet : hockey : nhl : david amber q&a, part i: \'my job is not to be ron jr.\'',
            section : 'sportsnet : hockey',
            subSection : 'sportsnet : hockey : nhl',
            contentName : 'david amber q&a, part i: \'my job is not to be ron jr.\'',
            complete90percent : false, // default: false
        }
```

output:

```
{
            "account" : "rogersrmisports",
            "brand" : "Sportsnet",
            "tags" : "",
            "cmsid" : "2912963",
            "wordCount" : "3197",
            "publishDate" : "July 11, 2016",
            "products" : "",
            "pages" : "sportsnet : hockey : nhl : david amber q&a, part i: 'my job is not to be ron jr.'",
            "section" : "sportsnet : hockey",
            "subSection" : "sportsnet : hockey : nhl",
            "contentName" : "david amber q&a, part i: 'my job is not to be ron jr.'",
            "complete90percent" : "false, // default: false"
        }
```

Comment: Can you fix the thing that gives you that invalid output?

Comment: from where you get this invalid input?may be there is a better way to fix this.can you tell more details

Comment: sorry i need this output :

{
 "account": "rogersrmisports",
 "brand": "Sportsnet",
 "tags": "",
 "cmsid": "2912963",
 "wordCount": "3197",
 "publishDate": "July 11, 2016",
 "products": "",
 "pages": "sportsnet : hockey : nhl : david amber q&a, part i: 'my job is not to be ron jr.'",
 "section": "sportsnet : hockey",
 "subSection": "sportsnet : hockey : nhl",
 "contentName": "david amber q&a, part i: 'my job is not to be ron jr.'",
 "complete90percent": "false, // default: false"
}

Comment: can you please help me with that ?

Comment: I have found this from a website html code

Comment: Maybe this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815586/convert-invalid-json-into-valid-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this. Please keep in mind that this eventually works just for your specified scenario. Other input can lead to problems. You have to check this yourself.

```
// use regex to get data
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/([A-Za-z0-9]*?)\s:\s(?:(?:\'(.*)\')|(.*)),/', $str, $matches);

// combine arrays of matches, remove slashes
array_walk($matches[2], function(&$val, $key) use ($matches) {
    if (empty($val)) {
        $val = $matches[3][$key];
    }
    $val = str_replace("\'", "'", $val);
});

// create data array
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);

// convert data array to json
$json = json_encode($result);


print_r($json);
```

Output:

```
{  
   "account":"rogersrmisports",
   "brand":"Sportsnet",
   "tags":"",
   "cmsid":"2912963",
   "wordCount":"3197",
   "publishDate":"July 11, 2016",
   "products":"",
   "pages":"sportsnet : hockey : nhl : david amber q&a, part i: 'my job is not to be ron jr.'",
   "section":"sportsnet : hockey",
   "subSection":"sportsnet : hockey : nhl",
   "contentName":"david amber q&a, part i: 'my job is not to be ron jr.'",
   "complete90percent":"false"
}
```