# How to read a scraped JavaScript object literal (with unquoted keys) "as JSON" in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have a json object scraped from a website

```
{
    area: {
        "lang": "en",
        "area": "25",
        "region": "mea"
    },
    config: {
        "rtl": false,
        "breakpoint": 768
    }
}
```

due to the season **area** and **config** is not enclosed in double quotes php function **json_decode** retuerns NULL

how to add double quotes in php to **area** and **config** if these are not already enclosed in double quotes?

Comment: That's not valid JSON, so it can't be a "json object".. anyway, updated the title to reflect the intent. YMMV.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert invalid json into valid json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815586/convert-invalid-json-into-valid-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex replace, (assuming the format).

```
$json = preg_replace('/([^"\s]+)+: ?{/', '"$1": {', $js_object);
```

[Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YrhUiK/1)

[PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/603f9e9d9ffce0cc97428a1f8efba7dc89b78932)

## Edit

For the supplied string, you need to check two more things:

- Make sure that the pattern isn't in a string (eg. `"Your selection: {packageName}"`)
- Make sure that the backslash character is escaped ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024#27516892))

Here's the updated code:

```
$js_object = '...';

$json_proper_backslashes = preg_replace('#\\\\([^"\\\\\/bfnrtu])#', '\\\\\\\\$1', $js_object);

$json = preg_replace('/({|},)\s*([^"\s]+): ?{/', '$1"$2": {', $json_proper_backslashes);

$json_object = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: look at https://regex101.com/r/YrhUiK/2 it is not working with my provided test string.

Comment: @DMP Thanks for supplying the string. I've tested it with my edited answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, your supplied text string is too long to store. Is it not working for you?

Comment: Okay, you need to use `({|},)\s*([^"\s]+): ?{` as well. Take the resulting string, then use https://regex101.com/r/YrhUiK/5